# with custom user i have not the group form in admin django

Tags: django

I created a custom user, it works well, but I notice that in the django admin, if I create a new user, I don't have access to the form that manages the groups.

If I use a standard user system, when you create a user, in the admin, you have access to the management of groups and permissions. On the other hand in my project group and user are not linked

my models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models


class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Vous devez entrer une adresse email.')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        user = self.create_user(email=email, password=password)
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save()
        return user


class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
        blank=False
    )
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, unique=True)

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

in the views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login as log_user
from django.contrib.auth import logout as logout_user

from accounts.forms import UserRegistrationForm
from accounts.models import CustomUser


def home(request):

    # return HttpResponse(f"Bienvenue {request.user} !")
    nom_user = request.user.nom
    #nom_user = CustomUser.objects.all()
    context = {'nom_user': nom_user}
    return render(request, "index.html", context)


def signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect("home")
    else:
        form = UserRegistrationForm()

    return render(request, "accounts/signup.html", {"form": form})


def profile(request):
    return HttpResponse(f"Bienvenue {request.user.email}")


def login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get("username")
        password = request.POST.get("password")
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            log_user(request, user)
            return redirect("home")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Impossible de connecter l'utilisateur...")

    return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {})


def logout(request):
    logout_user(request)
    return redirect("home")
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from accounts.models import CustomUser

@admin.register(CustomUser)
class CustomUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('email', 'nom', )
```

in settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "accounts.CustomUser"
```

thank for any help

Comment: By default you are dont have an access to the management of permissions directly. Only to GroupModelAdmin and to The UserModelAdmin. And AbstractBaseUser has not connections to groups. Are you probbaly forgot the PermissionsMixin or your Parent class should be AbstractUser, and not the AbstractBaseUser

Comment: thank you Maxim, if I put AbstractUser instead of AbstractBaseUser, I actually have access to the group management form but I have new problems, I had to overload REQUIRED_FIELDS because in AbstractUser it is filled in with email, and that's the fields of my USERNAME_FIELD, and it causes a bug. After I put an empty dictionary in REQUIRED_FIELDS and I put unique=False in my "name" field because unique= True was causing me problems. Then if I register a new user via the login form it causes an error "UNIQUE constraint failed: accounts_customuser.username".. I will rather try PermissionsMixin

Answer (score 2):

I added PermissionsMixin in CustomUser model

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin)
```

and in admin.py added this in fieldsets

```
('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_admin', 'groups',)}),
```

and now in admin I can link users to permission groups

Comment: Thanks for this answer. After this you have to makemigrations and migrate. User then gets fields: groups, is_superuser, user_permissions